# Obtain first string in an array which is not null using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string array and I need to use the first string in the string array which is not null. Lets consider this code snippet -

```
string[] strDesc = new string[] {"", "", "test"};

foreach (var Desc in strDesc)
{
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Desc))
      {
           txtbox.Text = Desc;
           break;
      }
}
```

So, according to this code snippet, txtbox should now display `"test"`.

To do this I have this code. This is working fine. But, I want to know if it is possible to use LINQ to obtain the same result and perhaps skip using an extra foreach loop?

Comment: Resharper is very helpful in such situations as it can tell when the loop can be converted to Linq and can actually convert it too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var result = strDesc.First(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

Or if you want to set it directly in the textbox:

```
txtbox.Text = strDesc.First(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

Mind you that `First` will throw an exception if no string matches the criteria, so you might want to do:

```
txtbox.Text = strDesc.FirstOrDefault(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

`FirstOrDefault` returns null if no element mathces the criteria.

Comment: OrDefault, incase there are no null strings.

Answer (score 8):

Just an interesting alternative syntax, to show that you don't always need lambdas or anonymous methods to use LINQ:

```
string s = strDesc.SkipWhile(string.IsNullOrEmpty).First();
```

Comment: First() throws an exception if strDesc contains only nulls. So, FirstOrDefault() can be used instead.

Comment: @Pavanred - yes I am aware of that, but you didn't define what behaviour you wanted if nothing was found. And since the question seems to *expect* at least one, throwing an exception may be the correct thing to do.

Comment: Yes, Of Course, Thanks. I noticed this when I tried it out and thought it would be good to share.

Answer (score 1):

in .net 4.0 you can use `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, but in earlier versions you need `IsNullOrEmpty`

```
string desc = strDec.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(s))
                       .FirstOrDefault() ?? "None found";
txtBox.Text = desc;
```